# 300 GB hard drive only shows 200 MB available

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I know for a fact I have over 300 GB on my laptop but this is all that shows up when i go to terminal and try to fix things by mounting or unmounting:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    1   7.7G  0 disk  
└─sda1                  8:1    1   7.7G  0 part  /cdrom
sdb                     8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                  8:17   0   243M  0 part  /media/ubuntu/e24aaa06-dd33-4c1
├─sdb2                  8:18   0     1K  0 part  
└─sdb5                  8:21   0 297.9G  0 part  
└─luks-c907dd6b-7f70-457e-9fa2-944da38af0c4
                      252:0    0 297.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root 252:1    0 295.9G  0 lvm   
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
                      252:2    0     2G  0 lvm   
sr0                    11:0    1     2K  0 rom   
loop0                   7:0    0   1.1G  1 loop  /rofs

$ sudo mount /dev/sdb5 /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It shows an encrypted LVM volume of 295.9G. What is the exact problem that you're trying to solve? Does the computer work/boot/etc?

Answer (score 1):

You have 300 G in the unmounted sdb5 partition. It looks like you might have encrypted it, but I am not familiar with encryption.